# How can I iterate over two large arrays while preforming string searches quickly?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have 2 MySQL tables as follows...

```
Users
    - id field
    - inventory field
    - old_inventory field

StorageInventory
    - id field
    - invoice_number
```

The inventory field, and old_inventory field store a JSON serialized string of various items that share the same structure as StorageInventory... In other words it's a large JSON string containing mange items with id's and invoice_numbers.

Now I used a MySQL query in PHP to pull ALL rows from each column into arrays... Like so...

```
// Assume that the functions return a complete list from the MySQL database.
$users_array = GetUsersFromDatabase();
$storage_array = GetStorageFromDatabase();
```

This works perfectly fine... But now I need to make it so I iterate over EVERY user in the users_array, then de-serialize the JSON inventory and old_inventory fields.

Then for EACH of the inventory items in the resulting array I need to check it against other inventory items and old_inventory items, and each storage_array items to look for duplicate invoice_numbers.

If a duplicate invoice_number is found it should print out where it was found, the invoice_number, and then continue searching for more duplicates.

My problem is that the PHP script takes FOREVER to execute once it starts preforming checks inside of the a multi-nested loop... Like this one... Note this is pseudopod to get my point across of everything that I need to happen..

```
foreach($users_array as $user)
{
    $inventory = json_decode($user["inventory"]);
    $old_inventory = json_decode($user["old_inventory"]);

    foreach($inventory as $item)
    {
        // Check each user for duplicates...
        foreach($users_array as $user2)
        {
            $inventory2 = json_decode($user2["inventory"]);
            $old_inventory2 = json_decode($user2["old_inventory"]);

            // Check the inventory for duplicates...
            foreach($inventory2 as $item2)
            {
                if($item["id"] != $item2["id"] && $item["invoice_number"] == $item2["invoice_number"])
                {
                    echo("Found a Duplicate Item in Inventory <br>");
                    echo("User IDs: " . $user["id"] . ", " . $user2["id"] . " <br>");
                    echo("Invoice Number: " . $item["invoice_number"] . "<br>");
                }
            }

            // Check the old_inventory for duplicates...
            foreach($old_inventory2 as $item2)
            {
                if($item["id"] != $item2["id"] && $item["invoice_number"] == $item2["invoice_number"])
                {
                    echo("Found a Duplicate Item in OldInventory <br>");
                    echo("User IDs: " . $user["id"] . ", " . $user2["id"] . " <br>");
                    echo("Invoice Number: " . $item["invoice_number"] . "<br>");
                }
            }
        }

        // Check the storage for duplicates...
        foreach($storage_array as $storage_item)
        {
            if($item["invoice_number"] == $storage_item["invoice_number"])
            {
                echo("Found a Duplicate Item in StorageInventory <br>");
                echo("Storage ID: " . $storage_item["id"] . " <br>");
                echo("Invoice Number: " . $item["invoice_number"] . "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}


// Now check the storage items with everything...
foreach($storage_array as $storage_item)
{
    // Check each user for duplicates...
    foreach($users_array as $user)
    {
        $inventory = json_decode($user["inventory"]);
        $old_inventory = json_decode($user["old_inventory"]);

        // Check the inventory for duplicates...
        foreach($inventory as $item)
        {
            if($storage_item["invoice_number"] == $item["invoice_number"])
            {
                echo("Found a Duplicate Item in Inventory <br>");
                echo("User ID: " . $user["id"] . " <br>");
                echo("Invoice Number: " . $item["invoice_number"] . "<br>");
            }
        }

        // Check the old_inventory for duplicates...
        foreach($old_inventory as $item)
        {
            if($storage_item["invoice_number"] == $item["invoice_number"])
            {
                echo("Found a Duplicate Item in OldInventory <br>");
                echo("User ID: " . $user["id"] . " <br>");
                echo("Invoice Number: " . $item["invoice_number"] . "<br>");
            }
        }
    }

    // Check the storage for duplicates...
    foreach($storage_array as $storage_item2)
    {
        if($storage_item["id"] != $storage_item2["id"] && $storage_item["invoice_number"] == $storage_item2["invoice_number"])
        {
            echo("Found a Duplicate Item in StorageInventory <br>");
            echo("Storage ID: " . $storage_item2["id"] . " <br>");
            echo("Invoice Number: " . $item["invoice_number"] . "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

I've been told sticking to a MySQL query to do it would be MUCH faster, but I don't think MySQL is capable of doing anything like what I just did strictly in MySQL... Does anyone have any solutions/ideas of how to accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: If you're doing heavy duty JSON manipulation you might want to look at a document store like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org) which can deal with that natively. Even [Postgres supports JSON indexes](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-indexing-jsonb/) which MySQL currently lacks. The only way to do this in MySQL natively might be to break out your JSON into proper relational tables for performance reasons.

Comment: @tadman Switching to a MongoDB is not an option for me, the project is too far along to switch to a new DB... I only need this script to work to detect if their are duplicate items... I don't mind if it's a bit slow, but right now it's pretty much going to run until the end of time...

Comment: You could sidecar MongoDB for your reporting purposes, that might work. Using Node.js might be faster than PHP as well. Otherwise you're stuck with what you've got here, and it will be painful.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 gives you most of what you need.  Especially 5.7.12.

Comment: Yes, it is better to stay inside MySQL, but not when searching inside JSON.